# Transform Array from one row Array to multiple row array

Tags: javascript, arrays, transform

i have an array that returns the values like this:

0: 1,2,3,4

i need it to return array values like this:

```
0: 1
1: 2
2: 3
3: 4
```

If im doing it with javascript, how can i go about it?

Comment: Input is `array`([1,2,3,4]) or `object`({0:[1,2,3,4]}) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a loop, eg.

```js
var object = { '0': [1, 2, 3, 4] },       // the object
    result = function (o) {               // the iife for the result
        var r = {};                       // the temporary variable
        o['0'].forEach(function (a, i) {  // the loop over the property zero
            r[i] = a;                     // the assignment to the object with
        });                               // the wanted key
        return r;                         // the return of the temporary object
    }(object);                            // the start with the object

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(result, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 1):

```
i have an array that returns the values like this:

0: 1,2,3,4
```

try this

```
"0: 1,2,3,4".split(":").pop().split(",").map( function(value){return [value]} );
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11505767)

Comment: @DanielCheung check now

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```js
var array = ['1,2,3,4'];
console.log(array[0].split(','));
```

Comment: i get this error:Uncaught TypeError: sortOrderValues[0].split is not a function

Comment: Can you do console.log(sortOrderValues) and give me the output, thanks